# Get JMS Queue ObjectName on Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, wildfly, mbeans

I want to get number of objects in Queue. This is the code I found:

```
MBeanServerConnection mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName queueName = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getJMSQueueObjectName(queue.getQueueName());
Integer messageCount = (Integer) mbeanServer.getAttribute(queueName, "MessageCount");
```

There's some problem with this code. First of all there's no `ObjectNameBuilder` class on wildfly (Is there any module required!?).

After using HornetQ ObjectNameBuilder class source code, I've implemented the function by myself, but now getting this error:

```
org.hornetq:module=JMS,type=Queue,name="MyQueueName"
```

I'm using `Wildfly v9.0.1-Final`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem and some details made all the difference.

If you are running Wildfly in domain mode so you must connect as follows:

```
HashMap environment = new HashMap();
environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, new String[] { "your_user", "your_password" });
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://your_host:8080");

JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, environment);
MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

Attention: Please note that the port for remote connection should be 8080, not 9990. Another important detail: your_user must be a user of the application type and no a mgmt type user.

Also you should leave the setting on your JMX domain.xml as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
   <expose-resolved-model/>
   <expose-expression-model/>
   <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false" />
</subsystem>
```

If you are running Wildfly in standalone mode must use the 9990 port and authentication is not required.

One more detail, try to recover the information as follows:

```
String queueName = "YourQueue"; // use your queue name jms-queue 

String mbeanObjectName = "jboss.as:subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-queue=" + queueName;

ObjectName objectName = ObjectName.getInstance(mbeanObjectName);

JMSQueueControl jmsQueueControl = (JMSQueueControl) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, objectName, JMSQueueControl.class, false);

assert jmsQueueControl != null;
long msgCount = jmsQueueControl.countMessages(null);
System.out.println(mbeanObjectName + " message count: " + msgCount);
```

Note that instead of using the key "org.hornetq:module=JMS,type=Queue,name=" I used "jboss.as:subsystem=messaging,hornetq-server=default,jms-queue=".

Ideally, use jconsole to verify the exact name of your key.